# Understant behavior of get() JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script JS which launches a get JQuery:

```
$(function () {
  var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById("fileDisplayArea");
  var file = "file/test.txt";
  var lines = [];

  console.log(file);
  $.get(file, { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function (data, status) {
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    lines = data.split("\r\n").map(function (row) {
      return row.split("-");
    });
  });
});
```

I don't understand that:

the `get` request  with `file/test.txt?name=john&time=2pm` is sent to the server **only** when the file doesn't exist.

I don't see that in the documentation. **is it the behavior of the get request?**

If I change to `post` the request is always sent to the server.

Comment: Browsers cache GET requests based on the URL. If you don't want the browser to do that, add a query parameter with a unique (random or time-based) value.

Comment: That's not how `$.get` works. It only sends a GET. It does not and ***cannot*** check whether a resource exists in order to make a request.

Comment: @Pointy could you elaborate more, its certainly the problem i have...

Comment: You can look at the browser "Network" tab and check what happens when your code makes the HTTP request. Or you could simply add `"?_=" + Date.now()` to the end of the URL and try it.

Comment: The behavior is what leads people to use Content Delivery Networks for things like jQuery or Google font files. The browser will not bother to fetch content that it already has in its cache.

Comment: ok i understand ! thanks for explanation!!

Comment: Modern jQuery permits `cache: false` if you use `$.ajax()`. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. It appears to just append a timestamp behind the scenes, which some of the commenters here are suggesting you do manually. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the different comments, the solution is (to avoid the cache):

(carefully: tested but undocumented)

```
$.get({url:file, cache:false}, { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function (data, status)
```

or

```
$.get(file, { name: "John", time: "2pm" , _:Date.now()}, function (data, status)
```

or using the $.ajax

Comment: The first version is not valid. If you give an object argument to `$.get`, that should be the only argument -- it's in the same format as for `$.ajax`

Comment: i have tested and the syntax is ok: when i log the value of uri, ihave:`http://localhost:8000/file/test.txt?name=John&time=2pm&_=1603782351979` with the first syntax, so the cache false is operational

Comment: It must be an undocumented feature, so you shouldn't depend on it continuing to work.